# how to handl image size when orientation change

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager with several fragments.Each fragments contain image.I need to show image center and take whole size of the space.It's fine in the horizontal,But when i change it to landscape it shows me small image.
below is my viewpager.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_back"
        android:text="" />


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/coverPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/coverDetails"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/coverPager"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

below is my fragment which contain image

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"    
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loadingIndicator"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/coverimage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/coverDate"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:padding="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/coverDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have already added the onConfigurationChanged method to my Activity

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        switch (newConfig.orientation) {
        case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
            coverViewPager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // mPDFView.setPageViewMode(PDFViewCtrl.PAGE_VIEW_FIT_PAGE);
            break;
        case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
            coverViewPager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // mPDFView.setPageViewMode(PDFViewCtrl.PAGE_VIEW_FIT_WIDTH);
            break;
        }
    }
```

below is are the screenshots of the relavant pages

[Horizontal](http://s693.photobucket.com/user/asliyanage/media/tempFileForShare_2014-12-07-01-00-46.jpg.html)

[Landscape](http://s693.photobucket.com/user/asliyanage/media/tempFileForShare_2014-12-07-01-01-17.jpg.html)

Answer (score 0):

Fill background of ViewPager by some contrast color to see changes of it's size after rotation. You have a lot of mistakes in first layout. Maybe there is a problem